# text display on mouse over field

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I am making a simple signup form of a website. i need to display a text line saying "manager or customer" It only should appear when i place my mouse  on the third field(type) of the form. I am new to these css things. i am sory if my question is odd but i need to do it.

```html
<!DOctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body{
    background: url("2.jpg"); 
 background-size: cover;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

div.transbox {
    width: 400px;
    height: 360px;
    margin: 30px 50px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 2px solid;
    border-radius: 25px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=60); 
}
span {
    display: none;
    border:1px solid #000;
    height:30px;
    width:290px;
    margin-left:10px;
}


input:hover  {
    background-color: brown;
}
form:hover{
    border-color: green;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>
</head>



<center><body>
<div class = "transbox">


<form
method = POST action = makeaccount.php>
<p>
<h1>Make Your account Here</h1>
   
<br> <br>  USERNAME &nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE = TEXT NAME = USERNAME>
  </p>
  
 <p>    <BR>
    USERPASS &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <INPUT TYPE="password" NAME = USERPASS>
    </p>
 <p>    <BR>
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; TYPE &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <INPUT TYPE= TEXT  NAME = TYPE>
    </p>
 
 <br> <BR>
    
   &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<INPUT TYPE =submit name="submit"  VALUE = "LOGIN">
  </p>
</form>
</div>

</body>
</center>
<br><br><br>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<form action="home.html">
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" style="width:100px; height:30px;" value="Back">
</form>


</html>
```

Comment: add that text as `title` attribute to the field. `<INPUT TYPE="TEXT " NAME ="TYPE" titel="manager or customer">`

Comment: why don't you make your `Type` input field a `select` (dropdown) with two options manager and customer. However it is relatively easy to do what you want.

Comment: `select` seems best, you could also add a [placeholder attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

(1) As mentioned in the other answers, best would be to use a `title` attribute:

```
<input type="text" id="userType" title="Manager or Customer" />
```

(2) Next best thing is to use `placeholder` attribute, <sub>(as mentioned by @Rhumborl in comments)</sub>:

```
<input type="text" id="userType" title="Manager or Customer" placeholder="Manager or Customer" />
```

(3) Alternatively, you could use a `span` following your input and show it by toggling its `display` on `hover` and/or `focus` of your `input`.

***Example (showing all three):***

```css
label { display: inline-block; width: 84px; }
span#typePrompt { display: none; }
input#userType:hover + span#typePrompt { display: inline; }
input#userType:focus + span#typePrompt { display: inline; }
```

```html
<label>Username: </label><input type="text" id="userName" /><br />
<label>Password: </label><input type="text" id="userPassword" /><br />
<label>UserType: </label><input type="text" id="userType" placeholder="Manager or Customer"  title="Manager or Customer" />
<span id="typePrompt">Manager or Customer</span>
<br />
```

Comment: downvoter: care to reason? anything wrong here? anything incorrect? does it not answer the question? why is this not useful?

Comment: It was Praveen.

Answer (score 8):

Use the `title` attribute!

```
<input type="text"  name="type" title="Manager or customer" />
```

Comment: Exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this by using the `title` attribute:

```
<input type="text"  name="type" title="Manager or customer">
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show it on mouse enter you can add following code

```
$("#type").mouseenter(function(){
    $(".textdis").show();
});
$("#type").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".textdis").hide();
});
```

Add it to your html

```
 <p class="textdis">Manager or customer</p>
```

Check it on this
http://jsfiddle.net/nikkirs/6jh944fn/5/

Or

If you wish to display it in textbox then you can use placeholder="Manager or customer" in input field

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one single line
`<div title="Hey show me the !!">hover me</div>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm not sure I understand how this adds anything to the existing ones that suggest using the `title` attribute [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248236/6243352), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248332/6243352) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27248362/6243352). Can you elaborate?